# Не работает ограничение ForeignKey в SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Никак не могу решить проблему - при добавлении записей в таблицу songs не работает ограничение ForeignKey, записи добавляются, даже если полю Song.song_genre_id присвоить значение, которого нет в таблице genres. При этом, если пытаться добавлять записи не через пайтон, а через менеджер базы данных (Использую DB browser for sqlite) все в порядке, ошибка возникает, запись не добавляется.

```
SongsDatabase = declarative_base()

#Таблица, в которой сохранены данные о жанрах
class Genre(SongsDatabase):
    __tablename__ = 'genres'

    genre_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    genre = Column(Unicode())

    #songs = relationship('Song', backref = 'genres')

    check_1 = UniqueConstraint('genre_id')
    check_2 = UniqueConstraint('genre')

#Таблица, в которой сохранены данные о песнях
class Song(SongsDatabase):

    __tablename__ = 'songs'

    song_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    song_genre_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('genres.genre_id'))
    song_link = Column(Unicode())

    #Checkings
    check_1 = UniqueConstraint('song_id')
    check_2 = UniqueConstraint('song_link')

    def __repr__(self):
        return('link: {0}, genre_id: {1},'.format(self.song_link, 
        self.song_genre_id))

#Таблица, в которой сохранены данные о пользователях бота
class User(SongsDatabase):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    #ID пользователя в базе данных
    user_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    #ID пользователя в телеграме
    telegram_id = Column(Integer())
    #Словарь песен, уже отправленных пользователю в строке JSON
    listened_songs = Column(Unicode())

    check_1 = UniqueConstraint('user_id')
    check_2 = UniqueConstraint('telegram_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

В SQLite поддержка консистентности внешних ключей по умолчанию [отключена](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). Как включить, описано в [документации](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html) Алхимии, в разделе Foreign Key Support.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```